# Replacing Characters in String

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, character

I am trying to replace all instances of a character in a string of text with another character but I'm not succeeding.

Suppose the text is

```
cat rat mat fat
```

I want the script to replace all the `t's to p's`

```
cap rap map fap
```

What I have is the following but it seems to do little for me.

```
SET /P MY_TEXT=ENTER TEXT:

SET T2P=P

SET NEW_TEXT=%TEXT=:T!T2P!%

MSG * %NEW_TEXT%
```

Comment: Just the 2 cents for the for loop: - Look for instruction about using ! instead of % for variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've got the `=` sign in the wrong place. Try:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /P MY_TEXT=ENTER TEXT:
SET T2P=P
set NEW_TEXT=%MY_TEXT:T=!T2P!%
MSG * %NEW_TEXT%
```

You can also do the expansion the other way round, i.e.

```
set NEW_TEXT=!MY_TEXT:T=%T2P%!
```

Comment: This now has a message box saying T=P which is not what I was after?

Comment: I see what whent wrong your reply says TEXt not MY-TEXT works now  :)

Comment: I found this technique *very* helpful, but found it doesn't work inside a `FOR` loop.

Comment: @Lizz: Variable expansion in a `FOR` loop can be tricky.  The variables normally are expanded before the `FOR` loop begins, you can fix some issues by enabling delayed expansion, see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php for more details and worked examples.

However, this technique is using delayed expansion already, so I'm not sure what you'd need to do to get it to work in a `FOR` loop.  I suspect it depends on what the `FOR` loop is doing and how it does it.

Comment: Yeah, I used Rob's page but it didn't address this. I was lucky and could move your solution *out* of the `FOR` loop *this* time, but have no clue how it could be done inside a `FOR` loop. Tried a simple one and it broke. :(

Answer (score 25):

Try this

```
setlocal 
set string=cat rat mat fat
set string=%string:t=p%
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use 'sed' like this:

```
echo "cat rat mat fat" | sed 's/t/p/g'  # outputs "cap rap map fap"
```

Comment: Says that the batch operation is not recognised?

Comment: `sed` is not recognised on windows unless you go out of your way to get it installed.

Comment: ohh sorry my bad. If you have ruby you could invoke `ruby -e 'puts ARGV[0].gsub("t","p")' "cat rat mat fat"`